# PowerBi to MySql live connection

Tags: mysql, powerbi

Can we create a live connection between PowerBi and MySql so that the dashboard reflects the changes made in the database without having to do a manual refresh from PowerBi desktop everytime?

I have tried scheduled refresh but i want a solution to reflect changes in dashboard in realtime, i.e everytime they are made in the database

Answer (score 0):

No - MySQL currently doesn't support DirectQuery:
[MySQL Capabilities supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/mysql-database#capabilities-supported)

> - Import
> - Advanced options
>
>   - Command timeout in minutes
>   - Native SQL statement
>   - Relationship columns
>   - Navigate using full hierarchy

Note that "DirectQuery (Power BI Datasets)" isn't listed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended for `production` environments. Because the `analytics queries` are generally very heavy as compared to the `operational queries` being served the `operational systems/applications`.

The correct and ideal approach to have `Power BI` fetches the data from `read-replica` or `stand` by DB servers irrespective of `mysql` or `any other database`, so that it won't deteriorate the performance of application users.

I hope this helps, and please modify your question if it doesn't answer your question, I'll reattempt the answer.

Comment: So what do you suggest for me to get a DirectQuery connection to MySQL database? Is there any other way using gateway or connectors?

Comment: You should go via Power BI gateway only